# Reindex dataframe inside loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, reindex

I'm trying to reindex the columns in a set of dataframes inside a loop. This only seems to work outside the loop. See sample code below

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
data2 = [[10,11,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]
data3 = [[19,20,21],[22,23,24],[25,26,27]]
index = ['a','b','c']
columns = ['d','e','f']

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data1,index=index,columns=columns)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data2,index=index,columns=columns)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data=data3,index=index,columns=columns)

columns2 = ['f','e','d']

for i in [df1,df2,df3]:
    i = i.reindex(columns=columns2)

print(df1)

df2 = df2.reindex(columns=columns2)

print(df2)
```

df1 is not reindexed as desired, however if I reindex df2 outside of the loop it works. Why is that?

Thanks
Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens for the same reason this happens:

```
a = 5
b = 6
for i in [a, b]:
    i = 4

>>> a
    5
```

Why? See [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967173/how-to-change-variables-fed-into-a-for-loop-in-list-form).

Concerning your problem, one way to go about it is create a `list` of reindexed dataframes like so:

```
reindexed_dfs = [df.reindex(columns=columns2) for df in [df1, df2, df3]]
```

and then reassign `df1`, `df2` and `df3`. But it's better to just keep using your newly created list anyways.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Camilo Martinez. That worked a treat, and great background about the best way to go about working with variables.